# Web API requests in 4.0 framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0

I have to use the 4.0 framework to create a web API but I am not able to make a request:

```
public class ChartDataApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<ChartDatum> GetData(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
    {
        return new List<ChartDatum>();
    }
}
```

I have this at the moment just to confirm that I can actually hit this action.  The request:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/api/ChartDataApi/GetData";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        lowerBound: lowerBound,
        upperBound: upperBound
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
         graph.draw(response);
    },
    error: function(message) {
         //error handler logic
    }
});
```

I just cannot hit this action.  I have tried converting it to a POST just to see if I could get it to work but to no avail.  Server error gives a 404 (had to modify in order to submit):

> GET http:// (url) : port# /api/ChartDataApi/GetData?lowerBound=0&upperBound=29 404 (Not Found)

I can make a request just fine so long as I don't try to pass any parameters either via the query string or through the request body.  I have also tried prefixing the parameters with the `[FromUri]` attribute but this also didn't work.

Here is the web api route config (simply the default):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I have made these sorts of requests before, but always in the 4.5 framework and think it may be a difference between frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting the wrong resource. In your case, you should issue a `GET` request to the `/api/ChartDataApi` endpoint.

`HttpGetAttribute` applied to the `GetData` method simply indicates that this method is responsible for hangling `HTTP GET` requests; there is no need to explicitly specify `GetData` method name in the request URI.

Comment: So you cannot reference actions by name in 4.0?  I know this is possible in 4.5 but wasn't aware this wasn't doable in 4.0.  I would like to have multiple GET actions on this controller if possible.  EDIT: After having tried removing the action name, I receive the same error.  Even renamed the action to "Get".

Comment: that seems about right... I recall routing improving between 4.0 and 4.5 for MVC .. I think you'll have to use metadata/data annotations (or simply 'attributes') more in 4.0

Comment: this difference is actually what turned me off to developing apis using MVC routing.. it was much cleaner and simpler to just add an IHttpHandler page or HttpModule and register the file as a route provider.. which is essentially what the framework is doing behind the scenes, if I recall correctly...in webforms, it's still my method..

Comment: you can reference actions by name, just modify the route template: `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

Comment: 4.0 doesn't infer the action name though right?.. you still need to specify it on the method.. I think